# Symfony/process/process library in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, background-process, symfony-process

I use Symfony/process/process library in Yii2 for background process.

```
  $process = new Process(['yii','test/action']);
    $process->run();
```

It work fine in localhost but it does not work in server.

{name: "Exception",…}
code: 0
file: "xxx\vendor\symfony\process\Process.php"
line: 144
message: "The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation."
name: "Exception"
stack-trace: [,...]
type: "Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\LogicException"

help me to solve this problem.

Comment: It looks like your server is configured to disable `proc_open` function. If you can edit the `php.ini` file try checking the `disable_functions` directive and remove `proc_open` from there. Warning: this function is probably disabled for security reasons. If you remove it from `disable_functions` you will allow php scripts to run other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$process = new Process([
    Yii::getAlias('@app/yii'),
    'test/action'
]);
$process->run();
```